# App stops in the launcher page and doesn't show error messages xamarin.foms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I start my app it opens the launcher screen and closes it showing me "unfortunately [appname] has stopped", it doesn't show any message on logs and it is happening only in my device (Android).
Once it shows a message "the target machine actively refused it", somenthing like this...
It happens after I begin to implement push notification...I was using xam.plugin.pushnotification, firebase api as well
I uninstall plugin.pushnotification, but the error still here
Has someone ever seen that?

--------------------edit--------------------

Searching, I saw this error on device log:

[image]

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
09-21 11:51:15.831  Samsung SM-G800H    Error   8096    AndroidRuntime  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application 
md583ab84639d21035a23b6a55e87c99374.MainApplication: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"md583ab84639d21035a23b6a55e87c99374.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip 
file "/mnt/asec/com.xamarin.docs.android.neoFly_Montana-
1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/mnt/asec/com.xamarin.docs.android.neoFly_Montana-1/lib, /vendor/lib, 
/system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4763)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5694)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Other error that I think that is relevant:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
09-21 11:51:15.831  Samsung SM-G800H    Error   8096    AndroidRuntime  Caused 
by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"md583ab84639d21035a23b6a55e87c99374.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip 
 file "/mnt/asec/com.xamarin.docs.android.neoFly_Montana-
 1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
 [/mnt/asec/com.xamarin.docs.android.neoFly_Montana-1/lib, /vendor/lib, 
 /system/lib]]
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
 at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
 ... 11 more
```

(they are not code, but stackoverflow only permitted I post it as a code. lol)
There are other things there but, for now, they seem to be the most important to investigate...

----------------------edit ---------------------

MainAplication.cs:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
//You can specify additional application information in this attribute
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application, 
 Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
      :base(handle, transer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services!
    }

    public override void OnTerminate()
    {
        base.OnTerminate();
        UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
    {
    }
}
}
```

My manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.xamarin.docs.android.neoFly_Montana" 
   android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission 
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission 
  android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
 <application android:label="neoFly_Montana.Android">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="mapskey" />

<!--push notification-->
<receiver
android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
android:exported="false" />
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>
```

There is a folder inside obj (that is not include in my proj) with the name that is mentioned in the error **md583ab84639d21035a23b6a55e87c99374**, inside is the a mainapplication class...

[image]

--------------------------edit---------------------

it happens only in Android 4.4 version

Comment: Your question is a little unclear - without more details nobody can guess a solution. Did you try to [debug](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-device/)?

Comment: I can't debug because it happens in the whole start of the app?
in launcher screen

Comment: I edited my question, but the error is really not clearly

Comment: I don't use xamarin so I can't say too much about it, but after reading the description it looks like that the debugger is starting the app. So if there is some kind of exception / error during startup, I'd assume there has to be an error message in you ide or an exception.

Comment: There isn't a exception, at least I can't see...my output is empty and my error list too

Comment: @JoycedeLanna What gets logged in `logcat`?

Comment: @SushiHangover device log?

Comment: On device log I saw an error now...I am putting it here in my question...

Comment: It's there now.

Comment: @JoycedeLanna Is `MainApplication` a `Android.App.Application` subclass?

Comment: @SushiHangover I think the problem is in my manifest, because I chaged it...But I have the older sctipt, and there is something that contains "md583ab84639d21035a23b6a55e87c99374" but in the new manifest, after I change it, it was deleted...then, i think the problem is there...I will post

Comment: Ok, I made a confusion, because inside the obj folder there is a manifest that has this md58... code there, then I get confuse....I am postting mainapplication.cs code here
But I think It was there when I created my code, like a default class...wait...